# How to search data between two dates in asp.net from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem: two days ago, was I face a problem in the history of the introduction of the history of the coordination I've dissolution. But now I want to look in the two periods of time I've attached by typing the code in the image please help when press button search get all data from database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh44o.png)

```
DataTable dt = PFUCommonCLass.Common.GetDataTableModify
                     (@"SELECT * FROM Tbl_Invoice
                        WHERE Fld_Date BETWEEN " + txtStartDate.Text + "And" + txtEndDate.Text + "");
                     )
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hJGolhxFJo). this explains it. You can use date picker
Sample code:

```
string query = @"select top 1 OrderNumber 
                from tblOrderMaster 
                where OrderedDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString here"))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", txtfromcal.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", txttocal.Text);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            // other codes
            // to fetch the record
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with 
            // e.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

write this query

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Invoice
                        WHERE Fld_Date BETWEEN @tdate1 and @tdate2;

cmd.parameter.Addwithvalue("@tdate1",txtstartdate.text);
cmd.parameter.Addwithvalue("@tdate12",txtenddate.text);
```

Comment: Your advice is similar to the other answer, but your code has some lowercase letters instead of uppercase in C# commands (`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", txtfromcal.Text);`) and single `parameter` instead of plural `Parameters`